# How to use the context created by the runtime API from the driver API

Tags: cuda, cuda-context

A library that I link to uses the cuda runtime API. Thus it implicitly creates a cuda context when first calling a cuda function.

My code (that uses the library) should use the driver API. Now, how can i get both (runtime and driver API) to work at the same time?

The library calls the cudaSetDevice function upon library init. (There's no way i can change this).

Can I somehow determine the context and tell the driver API to use that one?

Comment: Is it necessary to run the two in the same context? That is, can't you just ignore the fact that the library also uses CUDA?

Comment: It is strongly discouraged to use separate contexts. It seems that is is an expensive operation to switch contexts.

Answer (score 3):

`cuCtxGetCurrent()` gets the currect context (that might be created by the runtime)